# Apache .htaccess not working on a new VPS

Tags: php, webserver

We changed hosting, being from a normal server, to a VPS server. In this VPS server the operation is normal, however the `.htaccess` file is not being executed or read by the VPS.

Even being simple tasks, such as a redirection 301 as for example the code: ( `Redirect 301 /url.html domain.com/urlnova.html` ).

But when we tested it on the local apache server (XAMPP), it works normally, and on the previous hosting as well.

We created the file from scratch, and it still doesn't work. We spoke with VPS hosting support, in this case Hostinger, but they were unable to help.

Is there any way to enable `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3):

`.htaccess` usage in Apache httpd is controlled by the `AllowOverride` option. Although most shared-hosting providers enable all `.htaccess` features for customers, it is actually [disabled by default](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in Apache httpd with stock configuration.

Other web servers such as Nginx do not support `.htaccess` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Before anything, find out if Apache is indeed the web server running on your new VPS. For all you know, Nginx is running on the server since many hosting providers consider Apache and Nginx to be similar web servers when they aren’t. Especially in the case of `.htaccess` files which are 100% Apache-only items.

As [user1686 states in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/1767831/167207), your hosting provider needs to set `AllowOverride` to be set to `All` for `.htaccess` to work. And yes, on a default Apache install `AllowOverride` is not set to `All` despite the fact pretty much 99% of the Apache web servers and webs ites out there need `.htaccess` set to work. For example, Wordpress and Drupal (two of the most popular CMS systems out there) will not work at all without `.htaccess` set and running.

This for example is a directive that can be set in the bottom of the default `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to allow `.htaccess` to work in any directory in `/var/www/html`.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

It can also be set in a local Apache config file in a path like this:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzzz_local.conf
```

I used to append stuff like that at the bottom of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but nowadays personally find it cleaner for it to be set in the config files that get loaded *after* the main `httpd.conf` is loaded in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

But in general, the `AllowOverride All` needs to be set for the `.htaccess` to work.